# React Native (Android): Download mp3 file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, asp.net-core, ffmpeg

I get the youtube video link from the ui. I download the video from this link and convert it to mp3. I download it to my phone as mp3. The song opens on WhatsApp on the phone. but it doesn't open on the mp3 player. The song is not broken because it opens on WhatsApp too. Why do you think the mp3 player doesn't open? Could it be from the file information? I tried to enter some file information but it still won't open. For example, there is from information in songs played on an mp3 player. There is no from information in my song file. I tried to add it but it wasn't added.

.net 8 api return:

```
    [HttpPost("ConvertVideoToMp3")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertVideoToMp3(Mp3 data)
{
    try
    {
        string videoId = GetYoutubeVideoId(data.VideoUrl);

        var streamInfoSet = await _youtubeClient.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync(videoId);
        var videoStreamInfo = streamInfoSet.GetAudioOnlyStreams().GetWithHighestBitrate();

        if (videoStreamInfo != null)
        {
            var videoStream = await _youtubeClient.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(videoStreamInfo);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            await videoStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var videoFilePath = $"{videoId}.mp4";
            await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(videoFilePath, memoryStream.ToArray());

            var mp3FilePath = $"{videoId}.mp3";
            var ffmpegProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = $"-i \"{videoFilePath}\" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -id3v2_version 3 -metadata artist=\"YourArtistName\" -metadata title=\"YourTitle\" -metadata from=\"youtube\" \"{mp3FilePath}\"",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            });

            await ffmpegProcess.WaitForExitAsync();

            var file = TagLib.File.Create(mp3FilePath);

   
            file.Tag.Artists = new string [] { "YourArtistName"};
            file.Tag.Title = "YourTitle";
            file.Tag.Album = "YourAlbumName"; 
            file.Tag.Comment = "Source: youtube";
  

            file.Save();

            var mp3Bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(mp3FilePath);

            System.IO.File.Delete(videoFilePath);
            System.IO.File.Delete(mp3FilePath);

            return File(mp3Bytes, "audio/mpeg", $"{videoId}.mp3");
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound("Video stream not found");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

React Native:

```
     const handleConvertAndDownload = async () => {
    try {
      const url = 'http://192.168.1.5:8080/api/Mp3/ConvertVideoToMp3';
      const fileName = 'example';
      const newFileName = generateUniqueSongName(fileName);
      const filePath = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath + '/'+newFileName;

      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({videoUrl:videoUrl}),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Network');
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.blob();
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]); 
          };
          reader.onerror = reject;
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
      })
      .then((base64Data) => {
        // Dosyanın varlığını kontrol et
        return RNFS.exists(filePath)
          .then((exists) => {
            if (exists) {
              console.log('File already exists');
              return RNFS.writeFile(filePath, base64Data, 'base64', 'append');
            } else {
              console.log('File does not exist');
              return RNFS.writeFile(filePath, base64Data, 'base64');
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error checking file existence:', error);
            throw error;
          });
      })
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Success', 'MP3 file downloaded successfully.');
        console.log('File downloaded successfully!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
        console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think you should download a standard mp3 file for testing to verify if there is a problem with the MP3 after the YouTube link is downloaded, or if there is a problem with the code, this can narrow down the problem.

Comment: @JasonPan There is no problem there, but I solved the problem and there is no need for it, thank you.